# Understanding sklearn grid_search

Tags: parameters, scikit-learn, grid-search

I am struggling to understand how the `grid_search` class works. I want to find the best `max_depth` parameter which I can use with the `RandomForestClassifier`. I specified the possible options I wanted the search to run through, and I expected the module to output the "best fitting" `max_depth` option.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn import grid_search

iris= load_iris()    
forest_parameters = {'max_depth': [1,2,3,4]}
forest = RandomForestClassifier()
explorer = grid_search.GridSearchCV(forest, forest_parameters)
explorer.fit(iris['data'], iris['target'])
```

I expected my `explorer` grid search module to return with the best `max_depth` parameter, given the set of possible options `[1,2,3,4]`. Why is the default value of `None` still being used? How can I use `grid_search` to find "best-fitting" parameters?

```
Out[13]: 
GridSearchCV(cv=None, error_score='raise',
       estimator=RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
       ---> max_depth=None, max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=10, n_jobs=1,
            oob_score=False, random_state=None, verbose=0,
            warm_start=False),
       fit_params={}, iid=True, loss_func=None, n_jobs=1,
       param_grid={'max_depth': [1, 2, 3, 4]}, pre_dispatch='2*n_jobs',
       refit=True, score_func=None, scoring=None, verbose=0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are only the parameters the grid search was invoked with. To identify to the best parameters use `explorer.best_params_`, or you could find the estimator using `explorer.best_estimator_`, provided `refit` is enabled.

Comment: How do I access these values? `est_estimator_` and  `best_params_` aren't [listed methods](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV). In my example, I get Attribute errors when I examine `explorer.best_params_` and `explorer.best_estimator_`.

Comment: They are listed in the attributes section of the page you linked to. They should be there after calling `fit`.